# Python Function Equivalent to * for Expanding Arguments?

Tags: python, arguments

Is there a function equivalent to the * symbol, for expanding function arguments, in python? That's the entire question, but if you want an explanation of why I need that, continue reading.

In our code, we use tuples in certain places to define nested functions/conditions, to evaluate  something like f(a, b, g(c, h(d))) at run time. The syntax is something like (fp = function pointer, c = constant):

```
nestedFunction = (fp1, c1, (fp2, c2, c3), (fp3,))
```

At run time, under certain conditions, that would be evaluated as:

```
fp1(c1, fp2(c2, c3), fp3())
```

Basically the first argument in each tuple is necessarily a function, the rest of the arguments in a tuple can either be constants or tuples representing other functions. The functions are evaluated from the inside out.

Anyways, you can see how the need for argument expansion, in the form of a function, could arise. And it turns out you cannot define something like:

```
def expand(myTuple):
    return *myTuple
```

I can work around it by defining my functions carefully, but argument expansion would be nice to not have to hack around the issue. And just FYI, changing this design isn't an option.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the `*` syntax *does*; it is part of the `(...)` object call syntax, not a separate operator, so it cannot be applied outside of a function call.

Comment: *"changing this design isn't an option"* - why not? It seems like a fragile way of doing things, and doesn't support e.g. `kwargs`.

Comment: Basically, you're looking for a way to evaluate [S-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

Comment: @MartijnPieters

I think I see what you're saying and it seems to clear up what I was unable to reconcile in my head before. I kept thinking "if a function *did* exist to expand arguments, what would its return type be?". It seems I'll either have to work around it by carefully defining functions, or add a flag to indicate argument expansion on evaluation. Thanks for helping to clear that up.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because bosses :p. If it becomes truly prohibitive, I'm sure the higher ups will be willing to revisit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write your own recursive function that applies arguments to functions in nested tuples:

```
def recursive_apply(*args):
    for e in args:
        yield e[0](*recursive_apply(*e[1:])) if isinstance(e, tuple) else e
```

then use that in your function call:

```
next(recursive_apply(nestedFunction))
```

The `next()` is required because `recursive_apply()` is a generator; you can wrap the `next(recursive_apply(...))` expression in a helper function to ease use; here I bundled the recursive function in the local namespace:

```
def apply(nested_structure):
    def recursive_apply(*args):
        for e in args:
            yield e[0](*recursive_apply(*e[1:])) if isinstance(e, tuple) else e
    return next(recursive_apply(nested_structure))
```

Demo:

```
>>> def fp(num):
...     def f(*args):
...         res = sum(args)
...         print 'fp{}{} -> {}'.format(num, args, res)
...         return res
...     f.__name__ = 'fp{}'.format(num)
...     return f
... 
>>> for i in range(3):
...     f = fp(i + 1)
...     globals()[f.__name__] = f
... 
>>> c1, c2, c3 = range(1, 4)
>>> nestedFunction = (fp1, c1, (fp2, c2, c3), (fp3,))
>>> apply(nestedFunction)
fp2(2, 3) -> 5
fp3() -> 0
fp1(1, 5, 0) -> 6
6
```

Comment: This is really cool. I have to admit, I avoided generators/yield statements for a long time and it took me a while to wrap my head around the syntax (especially with the recursion). But in the process, I learned a good deal and believe this solution works! Thank you.